# Does lazy loading load the entire collection upon iteration?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lazy-loading, ienumerable

Does lazy loading load the entire collection even if you only iterate over the first item in the collection? Or does it only load the items that are iterated over within the collection?

...or do I have no idea what I'm talking about?

Comment: `ObjectContext` has an `ObjectMaterialized` event.  You could listen to this event as you iterate over a collection to find out.

Comment: @Alex Ford, are you interested in some particular case (entity-framework) or general case for IEnumerable? I.e. for a IEnumerable implementation nothing stops to to get items in set of 7 whenever you ask for one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lazy loading loads the whole collection when you start to iterate over the collection. Example: Suppose `user` 1 has the role "Role1", "Role2", "Role3" (`user.Roles` is `virtual`):

```
var user = context.Users.Single(u => u.Id == 1);
foreach (var role in user.Roles) // DB query happens here once
{
    Console.WriteLine(role.Name);
    if (role.Name == "Role1")
        break;
}
```

Although you never access `Role2` and `Role3` they have been loaded nonetheless.

Answer (score 5):

@Slauma's answer is correct--the entire collection is loaded when the navigation property is accessed for the first time. It has to be this way with "normal" navigation properties because the collection is just a regular ICollection<> and not an IQueryable<>.

However, there are two things you can do if you don't want the entire collection loaded. If you have a context available, then you can use the Query method to really load lazily. For example:

```
foreach (var role in context.Entry(user).Collection(e => e.Roles).Query())
{    
    Console.WriteLine(role.Name);    
    if (role.Name == "Role1")    
        break;    
}
```

You can take this a bit further if you know in advance which entity you are looking for. For example, to load just Role1 you could do:

```
var role1 = context.Entry(user)
                .Collection(e => e.Roles)
                .Query()
                .Single(r => r.Name == "Role1");
```

This post provides some more detail on the Query method:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx

If you want to make this more transaprent such that you don't need the context to be available when running the query, then check out these blog posts that explain how to make extra-lazy collections:

http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/03/28/extra-lazy-collection-count-with-ef-4-1-part-1/

and more general IQueryable-backed collections:

http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2011/03/30/a-more-general-queryable-collection/

Comment: I've also discovered that my answer was wrong with some more testing. Too much wishful thinking on lazy-loading part, I guess. Good explanation by the way.

Comment: What would your first example do regarding DB queries? Will it generate one query for a single role in every iteration? I had actually expected that again there is only one query for *all* roles when you start the iteration. Hm, interesting...

Answer (score 1):

It iterates over the projection once every time it iterates over the source enumerable.